# Keep form data after submit - multiple selected values

Tags: php

```
<select name="test[]" size="5" multiple >   
    <?php foreach($type as $key => $value) { ?>               
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php (isset($_POST['test']) && in_array($key, $_POST['test']) ? ' selected' : '') ?> ><?php echo $value['name'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>                                     
</select>
```

I want to understand: how can I keep selected data from selectbox (which can hold multiple selects) after submitting data.

Comment: You want to maintain the selected state of multi select drop down after form submit?

Answer (score 2):

Trye below code you have to echo the ternary operator

```
<select name="test[]" size="5" multiple >   
    <?php foreach($type as $key => $value) { ?>               
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php echo ((isset($_POST['test']) && in_array($key, $_POST['test']) ? 'selected' : '')); ?> ><?php echo $value['name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>                                     
</select>
```